# reshape a data.frame based on similar value in one column

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, tidyr

I have a `data.frame` with 2 columns, where values in second column are repeated. for example:

```
     HUGO                     Cell
1    CD28                 T cells
2    CD3D                 T cells
3    CD3G                 T cells
4    CD8A                lymphocytes
5    EOMES               lymphocytes
6    FGFBP2              lymphocytes
7    GNLY                lymphocytes
8    NCR1                 NK cells
9    PTGDR                NK cells
10   SH2D1B               NK cells
```

I want all values in column HUGO corresponding to a unique name in column cell get into a names list after each unique name.

for example

```
T cells: CD28     CC3D     C34
lymphocytes: CD8A    EOMES    FGFBP2  FGFBP2    GNLY 
...
```

I have tried
`reshape(data.frame, timevar = "HUGO",idvar = "Cell",direction = "wide")`
but it just returns number of values for each name in Cell column.

Comment: `split(df$HUGO, df$Cell)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some possibilities depending on what it is you want.  The first 5 use no packages.

**1) aggregate/c**  This gives a data frame whose second column is a character vector of HUGO names.

```
aggregate(HUGO ~ Cell, DF, c)
```

giving:

```
         Cell                      HUGO
1 lymphocytes CD8A, EOMES, FGFBP2, GNLY
2    NK cells       NCR1, PTGDR, SH2D1B
3     T cells          CD28, CD3D, CD3G
```

**2) aggregate/toString**  This gives a data frame whose second column contains character strings separating the HUGO names with comma.

```
aggregate(HUGO ~ Cell, DF, toString)
```

giving:

```
         Cell                      HUGO
1 lymphocytes CD8A, EOMES, FGFBP2, GNLY
2    NK cells       NCR1, PTGDR, SH2D1B
3     T cells          CD28, CD3D, CD3G
```

**3) unstack**  This gives a list, one component per Cell, whose components are each the HUGO names of that Cell.

```
unstack(DF)
```

giving:

```
$lymphocytes
[1] "CD8A"   "EOMES"  "FGFBP2" "GNLY"  

$`NK cells`
[1] "NCR1"   "PTGDR"  "SH2D1B"

$`T cells`
[1] "CD28" "CD3D" "CD3G"
```

**4) tapply**  This gives a matrix whose rows are Cells and whose columns are the ordinal number of the HUGO name.

```
DF2 <- transform(DF, seq = ave(seq_along(HUGO), Cell, FUN t= seq_along))
tapply(DF2$HUGO, DF2[-1], c)
```

giving:

```
             seq
Cell          1      2       3        4     
  lymphocytes "CD8A" "EOMES" "FGFBP2" "GNLY"
  NK cells    "NCR1" "PTGDR" "SH2D1B" NA    
  T cells     "CD28" "CD3D"  "CD3G"   NA
```

**5) reshape**  This uses `DF2` from the last alternative together with `reshape` to give a data frame:

```
reshape(DF2, timevar = "seq", idvar = "Cell", dir = "wide")
```

giving:

```
         Cell HUGO.1 HUGO.2 HUGO.3 HUGO.4
1     T cells   CD28   CD3D   CD3G   <NA>
4 lymphocytes   CD8A  EOMES FGFBP2   GNLY
8    NK cells   NCR1  PTGDR SH2D1B   <NA>
```

**6) spread**  This gives a `"tbl_df"` class object as output (which is a subclass of `"data.frame"`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF %>% 
   group_by(Cell) %>%
   mutate(seq = 1:n()) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   spread(seq, HUGO)
```

giving:

```
         Cell    1     2      3    4
1 lymphocytes CD8A EOMES FGFBP2 GNLY
2    NK cells NCR1 PTGDR SH2D1B <NA>
3     T cells CD28  CD3D   CD3G <NA>
```

**7) read.zoo**  `read.zoo` gives a zoo object whose times are the Cells.
 Since the times are actually character strings we use `FUN=identity` to avoid interpretation. `fortify.zoo` converts that to a data frame. `DF2` is from above.

```
library(zoo)

fortify.zoo(read.zoo(DF2, split = "seq", index = "Cell", FUN = identity))
```

giving:

```
       Index    1     2      3    4
1 lymphocytes CD8A EOMES FGFBP2 GNLY
2    NK cells NCR1 PTGDR SH2D1B <NA>
3     T cells CD28  CD3D   CD3G <NA>
```

**8) dcast**  This gives a data.table as output.

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(DF)
DT[, seq:=1:.N, by = Cell]
dcast(DT, Cell ~ seq, value.var = "HUGO")
```

giving:

```
          Cell    1     2      3    4
1:    NK cells NCR1 PTGDR SH2D1B   NA
2:     T cells CD28  CD3D   CD3G   NA
3: lymphocytes CD8A EOMES FGFBP2 GNLY
```

**Note:**

```
DF <- structure(list(HUGO = c("CD28", "CD3D", "CD3G", "CD8A", "EOMES", 
"FGFBP2", "GNLY", "NCR1", "PTGDR", "SH2D1B"), Cell = c("T cells", 
"T cells", "T cells", "lymphocytes", "lymphocytes", "lymphocytes", 
"lymphocytes", "NK cells", "NK cells", "NK cells")), .Names = c("HUGO", 
"Cell"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```